# Join only those columns that are non-NA

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataset with NAs in some rows for some columns:

```
DT <- data.table(ID=c(1, 2, 1:3), A=c(NA, NA, 1, NA, 3), B=c(4, 5, NA, 5, 6), C=c(7, 8, NA, NA, 9))
DT
#    ID  A  B  C
# 1:  1 NA  4  7
# 2:  2 NA  5  8
# 3:  1  1 NA NA
# 4:  2 NA  5 NA
# 5:  3  3  6  9
```

And a reference table

```
ref <- data.table(ID=c(1, 1:3), A=c(1, 1:3), B=c(1, 4:6), C=c(1, 7, NA, 9), VAL=c(111, 101:103), VAL2=c(112, 104:106))
ref
#    ID A B  C VAL VAL2
# 1:  1 1 1  1 111  112
# 2:  1 1 4  7 101  104
# 3:  2 2 5 NA 102  105
# 4:  3 3 6  9 103  106
```

Qn: How do I  left join `DT` with `ref` using non-NA columns for each row?

Desired output (newline added for emphasizing grouping):

```
   ID  A  B  C VAL VAL2
1:  1 NA  4  7 101  104

2:  2 NA  5  8  NA   NA

3:  1  1 NA NA 111  112
4:  1  1 NA NA 101  104

5:  2 NA  5 NA 102  105

6:  3  3  6  9 103  106
```

I tried to do it row-by-row as follows:

```
newcols <- c("VAL", "VAL2")
resLs <- lapply(split(DT, by="ID"), function(x) {
    #find those non-NA columns
    nonNACols <- names(x)[sapply(x, Negate(is.na))]

    #left join with ref table after subsetting the columns of ref table
    ref[, c(nonNACols, newcols), with=FALSE][x, on=nonNACols]
})

#combine the list of row results
ans <- rbindlist(resLs, use.names=TRUE, fill=TRUE)
setcolorder(ans, names(ref))
ans
```

It would be better if the solution can do it by some sort of groups rather than row by row. Any suggestions?

---

EDIT: finally nailed it after so many hours. Using the data.table by grouping:

```
cols <- c("ID","A", "B", "C")
newcols <- c("VAL", "VAL2")
DT[, grp := paste(names(.SD)[sapply(.SD, Negate(is.na))], collapse=""), by=seq_len(nrow(DT)), .SDcols=cols]

rbindlist(
    DT[, {
        vec <- names(.SD)[sapply(.SD, function(x) !all(is.na(x)))]
        list(list(ref[.SD, on=vec,
            c(vec, newcols), with=FALSE]))
    }, by=.(grp)]$V1,
    use.names=TRUE, fill=TRUE)
```

---

EDIT: another way to code it

```
cols <- c("ID","A", "B", "C")
newcols <- c("VAL", "VAL2")
DT[, grp := paste(names(.SD)[sapply(.SD, Negate(is.na))], collapse="_"),
    by=seq_len(nrow(DT)),
    .SDcols=cols]

setnames(DT[,
    ref[.SD, on=strsplit(.BY$grp, split="_")[[1L]], 
        c(paste0("i.", cols), paste0("x.",newcols)), with=FALSE], 
    by=.(grp)][,-1L], 
    c(cols, newcols))[]
```

Comment: It's a little unclear to me, since it looks like column binding, i.e. `cbind(DT, ref[, .(VAL, VAL2)])`

Comment: thanks, @docendo. I added one more row in the dataset. hope its clearer now

Comment: Still unclear. Why don't you just join on ID? `DT[ref, on = "ID", \`:=\`(VAL = i.VAL, VAL2 = i.VAL2)]` The other columns seem to be irrelevant.

Comment: a `left_join` on non-NA columns would be on `ID` the only shared column. It would give you 9 columns and 4 rows. I think you are confused what `left_join` means or possibly `non-NA` means?

Comment: this? `left_join(DT, ref[,-2:-4], "ID")`

Comment: ahh i see where you all are coming from. let me improve the sample data

Comment: What if you used `sqldf` like: `library(sqldf);
sqldf("SELECT l.*, r.VAL, r.VAL2
       FROM       DT as l
       LEFT JOIN  ref as r
       ON         l.ID = r.ID AND (l.A = r.A OR l.A IS NULL)
                  AND (l.B = r.B OR l.B IS NULL)
                  AND (l.C = r.C OR l.C IS NULL)")
`

Comment: @MikeH! that is a possible solution. and i will just need to program the sql on the fly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to match on something like `A = A OR is.na(A)`, etc. However, I don't think you can use `OR` conditions to merge `data.tables`. For complicated merge situations like these, I like to use `sqldf` instead:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("SELECT l.*, r.VAL, r.VAL2
       FROM       DT as l
       LEFT JOIN  ref as r
       ON         l.ID = r.ID AND (l.A = r.A OR l.A IS NULL)
                  AND (l.B = r.B OR l.B IS NULL)
                  AND (l.C = r.C OR l.C IS NULL)
                  AND (l.A IS NOT NULL OR l.B IS NOT NULL OR l.C IS NOT NULL)")

#  ID  A  B  C VAL VAL2
#1  1 NA  4  7 101  104
#2  2 NA  5  8  NA   NA
#3  1  1 NA NA 111  112
#4  1  1 NA NA 101  104
#5  2 NA  5 NA 102  105
#6  3  3  6  9 103  106
```

Note that the last condition insures that if all of your `A, B, C` are `NA` then it won't match any rows.