# Left joining data.tables on matching or NA columns

Tags: r, data.table

I have a number of tables that need to be joined on to. However, in certain cells, the value is NA which needs to match onto every possible value.

In SQL it might be like:

```
SELECT * FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
ON (A.KEY1 = B.KEY1 OR B.KEY1 IS NULL)
AND (A.KEY2 = B.KEY2 OR B.KEY2 IS NULL) # Repeated for every other column
```

I could work around this by doing many joins such as:

```
B[A, on = .(Key1, Key2, Key3), Var = i.Var]
B[A[is.na(Key2), ], on = .(Key1, Key3), Var = i.Var]
B[A[is.na(Key3), ], on = .(Key1, Key2), Var = i.Var]
B[A[is.na(Key2) & is.na(Key3), ], on = .(Key1), Var = i.Var]
B[A[is.na(Key1), ], on = .(Key2, Key3), Var = i.Var]
B[A[is.na(Key1) & is.na(Key2), ], on = .(Key3), Var = i.Var]
B[A[is.na(Key1) & is.na(Key3), ], on = .(Key2), Var = i.Var]
```

However this doesn't seem like the best method, especially as the number of columns increases. The above required 7 updating joins for just 3 columns.

For example, if I had one table that matched a description of someone (city they live in, hair colour, height) with a name:

Observed data:

```
a <- data.table(id = c(1, 2, 3),
            city = c("city1", "city2", "city2"),
            height = c("tall", "tall", "short"),
            hair = c("black", "black", "blonde"))
```

```
       id  city height   hair    name
    1:  1 city1   tall  black    dave
    2:  2 city2   tall  black william
    3:  3 city2  short blonde    jack
```

Table to match to:

```
b <- data.table(city = c("city1", "city1", "city2", "city2"),
            height = c("tall", "tall", "short", "tall"),
            hair = c("black", "blonde", "blonde", "black"),
            name = c("dave", "harry", "jack", "william"))
```

```
    city height   hair    name
1: city1   tall  black    dave
2: city1   tall blonde   harry
3: city2  short blonde    jack
4: city2   tall  black william
```

Joining them:

```
b[a, on = .(city, height, hair), .(id, city, height, hair, name)]
```

```
       id  city height   hair    name
    1:  1 city1   tall  black    dave
    2:  2 city2   tall  black william
    3:  3 city2  short blonde    jack
```

This above is as expected. I need it so that if certain fields were missing such as:

```
        city height   hair    name
    1: city1     NA  black    dave
    2: city1     NA blonde   harry
    3: city2  short     NA    jack
    4: city2   tall  black william
```

It should still produce the same output

Is there any way to do this within the data.table framework efficiently?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

To make it clearer, if table b was

```
    b <- data.table(city = c("city1", "city1", "city2", "city2"),
                    height = c(NA, "tall", "short", "tall"),
                    hair = c("black", "blonde", "blonde", "black"),
                    name = c("dave", "harry", "jack", "william"))
```

Then the join produces only:

```
       id  city height   hair    name
    1:  1 city1   tall  black      NA
    2:  2 city2   tall  black william
    3:  3 city2  short blonde    jack
```

When it should produce:

```
       id  city height   hair    name
    1:  1 city1   tall  black    dave
    2:  2 city2   tall  black william
    3:  3 city2  short blonde    jack
```

The NAs should be treated as "wildcards" where they will match to any value.

**EDIT2:**

A second work around I've found is by cartesian joining the tables first:

```
    ab <- a[, as.list(b), by = .(id, i.city = city, i.height = height, i.hair)]

       id i.city i.height i.hair  city height   hair    NAME
     1:  1  city1     tall  black city1     NA  black    dave
     2:  1  city1     tall  black city1   tall blonde   harry
     3:  1  city1     tall  black city2  short blonde    jack
     4:  1  city1     tall  black city2   tall  black william
     5:  2  city2     tall  black city1     NA  black    dave
     6:  2  city2     tall  black city1   tall blonde   harry
     7:  2  city2     tall  black city2  short blonde    jack
     8:  2  city2     tall  black city2   tall  black william
     9:  3  city2    short blonde city1     NA  black    dave
    10:  3  city2    short blonde city1   tall blonde   harry
    11:  3  city2    short blonde city2  short blonde    jack
    12:  3  city2    short blonde city2   tall  black william
```

And then applying my conditions after:

```
    ab[(i.city == city | is.na(city)) 
       & (i.height == height | is.na(height)) 
       & (i.hair == hair | is.na(hair))]

     id i.city i.height i.hair  city height   hair    name
    1:  1  city1     tall  black city1     NA  black    dave
    2:  2  city2     tall  black city2   tall  black william
    3:  3  city2    short blonde city2  short blonde    jack
```

I'm not sure if cartesian joining like this is the best way either though when using large datasets.

Comment: @akrun I've edited to include an example of it not working. What I want is if there was a field that takes values in A of 1 or 0 then in table B it should match to both itself (1 or 0) and NA. The reason I need this is because I have data where every column is populated but the table it matches to has blanks in certain rows, where it's intended to match to any value.

Comment: Can there be more than one `NA` column in the same row?

Comment: @Alexis it seems so (judging from the work around presented by OP).

Comment: @Alexis yes, the table being joined to (table B) could have NAs in every column in the join condition (in this case every row in table A would match to it). And Table A will have no NAs at all.

Comment: I can't think of an efficient way, but it might be doable more elegantly, I'm not sure. Is B small relative to A? And how many columns do you have in your actual data?

Comment: @Alexis I have multiple tables I'm using this for but the biggest B table I have is about 2000 rows with 22 columns (12 to join on and 10 that provide the required information). The largest A table is between 500k and a million.

Comment: i asked a similar qn in the past. might be relevant to your problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49873894/join-only-those-columns-that-are-non-na

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The least inefficient way I could think of was to simply expand B so that you can do a normal join afterwards.

```
library(data.table)

a <- data.table(id = c(1, 2, 3),
                city = c("city1", "city2", "city2"),
                height = c("tall", "tall", "short"),
                hair = c("black", "black", "blonde"))

a_unique <- a[, lapply(.SD, function(x) { list(unique(x)) })]

b <- data.table(city = c("city1", "city1", "city2", "city2"),
                height = c(NA, "tall", "short", NA),
                hair = c("black", NA, "blonde", NA),
                name = c("dave", "harry", "jack", "william"))

harmonize <- function(mat) {
  ans <- as.vector(t(mat))
  ans[!is.na(ans)]
}

expand_recursively <- function(dt, cols) {
  if (length(cols) == 0L) return(dt)

  current <- cols[1L]
  next_cols <- cols[-1L]
  not_current <- setdiff(names(dt), current)

  na_class <- class(a_unique[[current]][[1L]])
  expanded <- data.table(as(NA, na_class), all = a_unique[[current]][[1L]])
  setnames(expanded, c(current, "all"))

  next_dt <- expanded[dt,
                      c(list(harmonize(as.matrix(.SD))), mget(not_current)),
                      on = current,
                      .SDcols = c(current, "all"),
                      allow = TRUE]

  setnames(next_dt, "V1", current)
  expand_recursively(next_dt, next_cols)
}

b_expanded <- expand_recursively(b, intersect(names(a), names(b)))
setcolorder(b_expanded, names(b))

b
    city height   hair    name
1: city1   <NA>  black    dave
2: city1   tall   <NA>   harry
3: city2  short blonde    jack
4: city2   <NA>   <NA> william

b_expanded
    city height   hair    name
1: city1   tall  black    dave
2: city1  short  black    dave
3: city1   tall  black   harry
4: city1   tall blonde   harry
5: city2  short blonde    jack
6: city2   tall  black william
7: city2   tall blonde william
8: city2  short  black william
9: city2  short blonde william
```

I think a problematic thing may be computing `a_unique`.
If you know the possible values that can be used to match,
maybe you can specify them directly inside `expand_recursively`.

Comment: This seems a much better method that what I'm doing. I just tried it and it's not expanding my B table fully though. Using a small sample, it expanded a B table of 1000 to 5000 rows and matched 199/600 of my sample A table.The a_unique is working fine but there's still some NAs not being expanded it seems (but only for certain rows). I'll try tweaking the function to get it working. Thanks for the help

Comment: Do let me know if you find the error, I think this use case is interesting.

Comment: @harv now that I think about it, that might be normal, because it's only expanding the columns that are actually present in A. I suppose I could explain the code a bit.

Comment: I just tried it again and it's worked, I must've done something stupid without realising. Thanks again!